# sort write failed standard output broken pipe--Linux

Tags: linux, sorting, awk

I am using following commands in my script:

```
max_length=`awk '{print length}' $File_Path_Name/$filnm | sort -nr | head -1`;
min_length=`awk '{print length}' $File_Path_Name/$filnm | sort -nr | tail -1`;
```

where the `filenm` variable contains the name of the file and `File_Path_Name` contains the directory path.
While executing this from script I am getting the error

> sort: write failed: standard output: Broken pipe

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong.  The error message is just telling you that `head` terminated and sort tried to write data to a broken pipe.

Comment: Well, you really shouldn't be sorting data (twice!) just to get the max and min, so that's something you're doing wrong.

Comment: I am basically using min and max length values to get line length like this Line_Length=`echo $(( ($max_length + $min_length)/2 ))`;                               and then checking value for line_length = required value, if yes pass it if no log an errror.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to scan the file twice for getting max/min
try

```
$ read max min < <(awk '{print length}' file | sort -nr | sed -n '1p;$p' | paste -s)
```

or you can avoid sorting as well by calculating max/min within `awk`

```
$ awk    '{len=length} 
   NR==1  {max=min=len} 
   max<len{max=len} 
   min>len{min=len} 
   END    {print max, min}' file
```

Comment: Thank you very much...i used awk suggestion ...it worked